# List transitions in vuejs, changing the underlying array

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs-transition

I need to be able to animate drag and drop in my vertical list. I used `vuedraggable`, wrapped my list in a `transition-group` and it all worked sweet. Until I fetch new data from the server. Now because of the introduction of `transition-group` for a split second the old data and the new data live together in the DOM causing the expansion of the list and pushing subsequent `div` down and back up.
This is kind of expected per the docs:

> the DOM operations for insertion and/or removal will be executed
>   immediately on next frame (Note: this is a browser animation frame,
>   different from Vue’s concept of nextTick).

Regardless of being able to drag and drop the element, if we were to fade in/fade out the new/old elements they will co-habitate for the time of the animation, which is not great [as seen in this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPzpjM)

Anyway to fade out, change the data, then fade in the new one, while maintaining the height of the list?

Note that without fade the problem is still obvious:
[Pen of my issue:](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgXVzr) click the switch data button to see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's [pretty know issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3974). By reading through this thread and toying with [this example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/examples/move-animations/index.html), i was able to achieve something to my liking by using:

```
list-leave-active {
 display: none;
}
```

[Resulting Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxyxeV)

Answer (score 0):

A css fix may be to wrap the contents within a box of some height and set overflow hidden.

So, even when new elements co-exist the jump in scrollbar can be avoided.